# Compiling Blender - Python 3.9

Tags: python, compile

I've been compiling Blender for a short time now and use the scripts `make update` and `make`.

In one of the recent updates, it seems the python dependency changed to Python 3.9

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:842 (message):   At least Python 3.9 is
> required to build

So of I installed Python 3.9. on my system. I then used

```
# update-alternatives
```

I now have:

```
# python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

But when I run `make`, I still see the original error.

```
# make

Configuring Blender in "/xxx/yyy/3D/Blender/blender-git/build_linux" ...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:842 (message):
  At least Python 3.9 is required to build
```

I haven't been able to discern anything in the error logs that can help me out.

Does anybody have ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Rather than install a system python, suggest you  download and build python.3.9.2 tarball from ftp.python.org (ibuilds to /opt folder in ubuntiu when using install deps script) and point the cmake python tags at it.  _

Comment: (ibuilds to /opt folder in ubuntiu when using install deps script) and point the cmake python tags at it.

Could you please expand with more detail on this or point me to some documentation please?

Comment: @batFINGER cheers, the variables starting with “PYTHON_” in CMakeCache.txt were still pointing to the previous Python version that comes down with `make update`. I went through and edited all of these to use the new python version. `make` now works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` fails because of Python version, but I did not realise that Blender comes bundled with it's own Python package. So in the latest `make update` the code / scripts came bundled with latest Python version that they should be built against.

The following article gave me a hint for the solution.
[Building Blender with a different Python version](https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/building-blender/)

I edited `./build_linux/CMakeCache.txt`

changing  the all of the Python version number references
to that of the new version found in

```
./lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/bin/
```

I could then successfully built Blender from source again.

Comment: Highly recommend cmake-gui for editing cmake configurations. Can generally make minor (or completely remove entries) changes and let it configure / generate the tags for you.

Comment: Cheers, @batFINGER, I didn't know that existed.

Comment: Deleting the CMakeCache.txt seems to do the trick as well, it get recreated when you build

Comment: Thank you @Youdje!